# how to verify OS port is available by erlang code?

Tags: erlang

I want to write code for checking OS port resource is available or not. Because the code runs on different os platform, to use bash script is the last choice.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the port and see if that fails.

```
port_available(Port)
    case gen_tcp:listen(Port, []) of
        {ok, Sock} -> 
            ok = gen_tcp:close(Sock),
            true;
        _ -> 
            false
    end.
```

This code makes sure the port is closed after a successful open attempt.